# Need to optimize code snippet in ms access vba

Tags: vba, ms-access, while-loop

We have a txt file with more than 100,000 records. We are importing this into a Microsoft Access database. The file has 4 columns separated by space (vbTab as separator, "Sep" variable in code). The given code separates each column value from each row and stores in temporary variables. Then using sql it is inserted into database.

This code use used to take at most 10 minutes to complate. Currently it is taking around 1 hour for same data. Can anyone please help. Will query optimization resolve or there is another issue.

```
While Not EOF(1)
Line Input #1, WholeLine
If WholeLine = "" Then GoTo EndMacro
NextPos = InStr(1, WholeLine, Sep)
TempVal1 = Mid(WholeLine, 1, NextPos - 1)
Pos = NextPos + 1
NextPos = InStr(Pos, WholeLine, Sep)
TempVal = Mid(WholeLine, Pos, NextPos - Pos)
strSignum = Trim(TempVal)
Pos = NextPos + 1
NextPos = InStr(Pos, WholeLine, Sep)
TempVal2 = Mid(WholeLine, Pos, NextPos - Pos)
Pos = NextPos + 1
NextPos = InStrRev(WholeLine, Sep)
TempVal3 = Mid(WholeLine, NextPos, Len(WholeLine) - NextPos)
If strSignum = "" Then GoTo NextRow
    strSQL1 = "INSERT INTO HRMS_DATA 
(User,OrgUnit,JobName,ParentOrganizationUnit) VALUES('" & Trim(TempVal) & "','" & Trim(TempVal1) & "','" & Trim(TempVal2) & "','" & Trim(TempVal3) & "');"

DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL1
RowNdx = RowNdx + 1
NextRow:
Wend

GoTo EndMacro
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `DoCmd.TransferText` method? [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-transfertext-method-access)

Comment: I don't know how many records are you importing, but in my case In my job, got some macros that import into MS Access Database around 25.000 records daily into temp table. First, I use Excel to organise my TXT data into the columns i need in a template file adapted to exportation needs. And then I use `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet Method` to import the 25.000 records to Access. It takes about 1 minute. Biggest isue is creating the template file. More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/office/ff844793(v=office.14).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all that VBA code.
Create an import specification, save it and use the Do.Cmd TransferText method.
Here's a step to step guide:

[Creating an Import Specification in Access 2003](https://access-programmers.com/creating-an-import-specification-in-access-2003)

Answer (score 0):

this is a record set task - not a coding task.  you are using the wrong approach.  Do as Rene posts - or another way is:

create a link to the text file
set up a Make Table query using the text file as the source